# Is it Logical Creating Separate Java Class for Database Table?

Tags: java, sql-server, database, jdbc

I have 5 different tables in my database on MS SQL Server 2012. I have created class for my UserTable and filled in setters and getters shown below , is it logical to put other tables's setters and getters inside the same glass or create separate class for other tables with setters and getters.

```
 import java.math.BigDecimal;
 import java.sql.Connection;


public class UserFR17setget {

    Connection cn;
    BigDecimal userID;
    String UserName;
    String UserPassword;
    int UserSecurity;
    BigDecimal ProjectID;


    public BigDecimal getUserID() {
        return userID;
    }

    public void setUserID(BigDecimal userID) {
        this.userID = userID;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return UserName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String UserName) {
        this.UserName = UserName;
    }

    public String getUserPassword() {
        return UserPassword;
    }

    public void setUserPassword(String UserPassword) {
        this.UserPassword = UserPassword;
    }

    public int getUserSecurity() {
        return UserSecurity;
    }

    public void setUserSecurity(int UserSecurity) {
        this.UserSecurity = UserSecurity;
    }

    public BigDecimal getProjectID() {
        return ProjectID;
    }

    public void setProjectID(BigDecimal ProjectID) {
        this.ProjectID = ProjectID;
    }

}
```

Regards

Comment: are you using JPA? it totally depends on the purpose

Comment: can I use JPA with Ms Sql Server ? Currently I am not using !

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbqn.html  also check this 
http://java.dzone.com/articles/jpa-implementation-patterns-mapping

Comment: Yes you can use JPA with MS Sql server and many other database.

Comment: Well basically it is up to you...basically I prefer to create one class for one table even when I use JDBC o SpringTemplate; it allows to me to work with objects; if you use JPA or Hibernate you must create classes mapping your tables; and yes yo can use JPA with Ms SQL Server

Comment: Use a separate .java for a class. Put them in the same subdirectory, aka java package, like: `package myprojoect.database.entitys;`.

Comment: The `Connection` object doesn't really belong to the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're basically implementing a part of `JPA` yourself. In `JPA` a class maps to a database table, and you think in terms of entities instead of database tables. You might want to explore that later on (unless you wish to do so now).

If you just want to map database data into objects, you have a few reasonable choices. Do as you're doing now, make each database table have a related class (`User` is a lot better name for a class than `UserFR17getset` by the way), then you can manipulate the data as objects. A more higher level approach is to have the classes reference to other tables, so your `User` class would contain an `Address` reference (assuming there's a table Address), and when loading a `User`, it would also load the `Address`. This is similar to how `JPA` works, and then you would be able to do a single "load user 1" instead of "load user 1, load address for user 1". Of course you would be responsible for implementing the actual loading (unlike with `JPA`, where there's a lot of automation going on).

Don't make the `Connection` object a part of your class though, it has no business being there. You should use the `Connection` object with your loading method, such as `User u = loadUser(connection, userId);`

Comment: do you have samples for loading method !

Comment: That's between you and the JDBC API. There's plenty of tutorials on how to make the queries.